# SQL query - need to exclude if Requirement NOT met, and exclude if Disqualifier IS met

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a feeling once i see the solution i'll slap my forehead, but right now I'm not seeing it.

I have a lookup table, say `TableB`, which looks like this. All fields are `INT` except the last two which are BOOL.

```
ID, TableA_ID, Value, Required, Disqualifies
```

I have a list of `TableA_Id` values `(1, 2, 3 )` etc

For each record in this table, either Required can be true or disqualified can be true - they cant both be true at the same time. They can both be false or null though. There can be duplicate values of `TableA_Id` but there should never be duplicates of `TableA_Id` and `Value`

If required is true for any of those TableA_ID values, and none of those values are in my list, return no records. If none of the values are marked as required `(required = 0 or null)` then return records **UNLESS** any of the values are marked as Disqualifies and are in the list, in which case i want to return no records.

So - if a field is required and i dont have it, dont return any records. If a field is marked as disqualified and i have it, don't return any records. Only return a record if either i have a required value or don't have a disqualified value or there are no required values.

I hope I explained myself clearly.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

As an example of what my records might look like:

```
ID  TableA_ID  Value  Required  Disqualifies
--  ---------  -----  --------  ------------
1   123        1      True      False
2   123        2      True      False
3   123        3      False     False
4   123        4      False     True
5   456        1      False     True
6   456        2      False     False
```

Given this set of sample data, if we're working with `TableA_Id` 123 and my list of values is lets say 1 and 3, i would get data returned because i have a required value and dont have any disqualified values. If my list of values were just 3, i'd get no records since i'm missing of the Required values. If my list of values were 1 and 4, i'd get no records because 4 is marked as disqualified.

Now if we're working with `TableA_Id` 456, the only list of values that would return any records is 2.

Maybe i should post the whole SQL query - i was trying to keep this short to make it easier for everyone, but it looks like maybe that's not working so well.

Here is the full dynamically generated query. The bit i am working on now is the 2nd line from the bottom. To equate this to my example, `t.id` would be `TableA_ID`, `Value` would be `PDT_ID`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, t.BriefTitle, stat.Status, lstat.Status AS LocationStatus, st.SType, t.LAgency, l.City, state.StateCode
,( SELECT TOP 1 UserID  
FROM TRecruiter 
WHERE TrialID = t.ID AND Lead = 1 ), l.ID as LocationID
, l.WebBased 
FROM Trial t 
INNER JOIN Location l ON t.ID = l.TrialID       
FULL JOIN pdt on t.ID = pdt.trialid       
FULL JOIN pdm on t.ID = pdm.TrialID       
FULL JOIN s on t.ID = s.TrialID       
FULL JOIN hy on t.ID = hy.TrialID       
FULL JOIN ta on t.ID = ta.TrialID       
FULL JOIN stt on t.ID = stt.TrialID       
FULL JOIN [Status] stat ON t.StatusID = stat.ID       
FULL JOIN st ON t.StudyTypeID = st.ID       
FULL JOIN State state ON l.StateID = state.ID       
FULL JOIN [Status] lstat ON l.StatusID = lstat.ID       
FULL JOIN ts ON t.ID = ts.TrialID       
FULL JOIN tpdm ON t.ID = tpdm.TrialID      
WHERE ((t.ID IS NOT NULL) 
AND (EligibleHealthyVolunteers IS NULL OR EligibleHealthyVolunteers = 1 OR (0 = 0 AND EligibleHealthyVolunteers = 0)) 
AND (eligiblegenderid is null OR eligiblegenderid = 1 OR eligiblegenderid = 3) 
AND ((EligibleMinAge <= 28 AND EligibleMaxAge >= 28) OR (EligibleMinAge <= 28 AND EligibleMaxAge is null) OR (EligibleMinAge IS NULL AND EligibleMaxAge >= 28)) 
AND (HYID = 6 AND (hy.Disqualify = 0 OR hy.Disqualify IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM hy WHERE t.id = hy.TrialID AND hy.Req =1)) OR HYID = 6 AND hy.req = 1)
AND (PDT_ID IN (1) AND ( pdt.Disqualify = 0 OR pdt.Disqualify IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (select * from pdt where t.id = pdt.TrialID AND pdt.Req = 1)) OR PDT_ID IN (1) AND (pdt.Req = 1 AND (pdt.Disqualify = 0 or pdt.Disqualify is null )))      
) AND ((3959 * acos(cos(radians(34.18)) * cos(radians(l.Latitude)) * cos(radians(l.Longitude) - radians(-118.46)) + sin(radians(34.18)) * sin(radians(l.Latitude)))) <= 300 OR l.Latitude IS NULL) AND t.IsPublished = 1 AND (t.StatusID = 1 OR t.StatusID = 2)
```

I've changed/shortened some table names just for security/privacy reasons.

**Edit:**
I think i am close to getting this working, but I'm getting tripped up on the logic again.

I have the following bit of sql:

```
AND ( exists (SELECT * FROM  pdt WHERE Req = 1 AND trialid = t.id AND pdT_ID IN (2) )  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  pdt WHERE Req = 1 AND trialid = t.id    )     )
```

I'm not sure how to structure this. Those two exists statement should make the whole thing true in the following combination:
True & False
True & True
False & False

If it's False & True, then the whole thing is false. In other words if there is a Req =1 AND the PDT_ID that is marked as Req=1 is not in our list (in the example above the list just contains '2') then return false.

**EDIT:**
I think i finally got it.

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  pdt WHERE Disqualify = 1 AND trialid = t.id AND  PDT_ID IN (2)  )
AND NOT ( NOT exists (SELECT * FROM  pdt WHERE Req = 1 AND trialid = t.id AND PDT_ID IN (2) )  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  pdt WHERE Req = 1 AND trialid = t.id    )  )
```

So far this seems to work in testing. Although I'm only working with two values of PDT_ID. If this does resolve my problem, i will come back and give someone the credit for helping me.

Comment: i want to know which one of the you want to return... 
`A). required = 1 and exists in the TableA
B). NOT required and diqualifies 0
C). NOT required and diasqualifes = 1 and exists in TableA`
? am i right?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - after the EDIT and explanation from OP:**

Change the line

```
FULL JOIN pdt on t.ID = pdt.trialid
```

To

```
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM pdt BB WHERE
BB.TrialID IN (SELECT AA.ID FROM Trial AA WHERE AA.ID = BB.TrialID) AND
1 > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Trial A
LEFT OUTER JOIN pdt B ON B.Req != 1 AND B.Disqualify != 1 AND B.TrialID = A.ID
WHERE B.TrialID IS NULL)) pdt ON t.ID = pdt.TiralID
```

AND change the line before last from

```
AND (PDT_ID IN (1) AND ( pdt.Disqualify = 0 OR pdt.Disqualify IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (select * from pdt where t.id = pdt.TrialID AND pdt.Req = 1)) OR PDT_ID IN (1) AND (pdt.Req = 1 AND (pdt.Disqualify = 0 or pdt.Disqualify is null )))
```

To

```
AND PDT_ID IN (1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure i can use this exactly, since this query is part of a larger dynamic query. The bit i'm working on is the where clause of the larger query. But I'm going to play around with the code you just gave me to see if i can make it work. If i can, I'll give you the credit for the answer - back in a few minutes. Thanks

Comment: I think it wont work as expected with this condition of the op... `If none of the values are marked as required (required = 0 or null) then return records`.. you are saying that all must be in the `Table A` with the `BB.TableA_Id IN (SELECT AA.TableA_Id FROM TableA_IDs AA) `

Comment: the value of tableA_Id is being taken care of elsewhere in the larger sql statement. It's `Value` that is the real field I'm interested in here. For each value of `Value` it can be marked either required, disqualified, or neither. Let me post an example in my original post since i think it'll be more useful there then in this comment.

Comment: @merk thanks for the example... from what I can gather your query won't allow you to just change the "second line from the bottom" - basically because it processes records independently... what you want is to make one record (disqualified or "required missing") determine the outcome for other records too... this would require a substantial redsign of the query for which you don't provide enough information...

Comment: please see the full query i posted above, does that help?

Comment: @merk please explain all tables/fields and their relationships that are used in the line before the last...

Comment: @merk please my UPDATE above... the query you gave is rather complex and without some knowledge of your data model AND what exactly this query should it is hard to help... perhaps the above gives you some inspiration in the right direction...

Comment: Thank you very much for that code. Unfortunately it's not working. It's returning zero records no matter what the values are. If it's ok with you, could i just email you the full sql that's being generated without my changing any of the table names? I'd prefer not posting that here. I completely understand if you do not want to give out your email. Or is there a way for me to message you directly on here? either way, i appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7582/discussion-between-merk-and-yahia)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEB B
WHERE 
(
   B.REQUIRED = 1 
   AND EXISTS
   (
     SELECT 1
     FROM TABLEA A
     WHERE A.ID =B.TABLEA_ID
   )
)
OR
(
  B.REQUIRED != 1
  AND B.DISQUALIFIES <> 1

)
OR
(
    B.REQUIRED != 1
    AND B.DISQUALIFIES = 1
    AND EXISTS
    (
     SELECT 1
     FROM TABLEA A
     WHERE A.ID =B.TABLEA_ID
    ) 

)
```

Answer (score 0):

*(You seem to have found a solution, yet I've decided to share my thoughts about this problem anyway.)*

Given you've got a set of `TableA` IDs, each of which is accompanied by a set of some values, and you want to test the entire row set against this `TableB` thing using the rules you've set forth, I think the entire checking process might look like this:

1. Match every pair of `TableA.ID` and `Value` against `TableB` and get aggregate maximums of `Required` and `Disqualifies` for every `TableA.ID` along the way.
2. Derive a separate list of `TableA_ID` values with their corresponding maximum values of `Required`, from `TableB`. That will be for us to know whether a particular `TableA_ID` *must* have a required value at all.
3. Match the row set obtained at Stage 1 against the derived table (Stage 2) and check the aggregate values:

   1) if the actual aggregate `Disqualifies` for a `TableA_ID` is `1`, discard this `TableA_ID` set;

   2) if a `TableA_ID` has a match in the Stage 2 derived table and the aggregate maximum of `Required` that we obtained at Stage 1 doesn't match the maximum `Required` in the derived table, discard the set as well.

Something tells me that it would be better at this point to move on to some sort of illustration. Here's a sample script, with comments explaining which part of the script implements which part of the description above:

```
;
WITH

/* this is the row set to be tested and which
   is supposed to contain TableA.IDs and Values */
testedRowSet AS (
  SELECT
    TableA.ID AS TableA_ID,
    SomethingElse.TestedValue AS Value,
    ...
  FROM TableA
    JOIN SomethingElse ON some_condition
    ...
),

/* at this point, we are getting the aggregate maximums
   of TableB.Required and TableB.Disqualifies for every
   TableA_ID in testedRowSet */
aggregated AS (
  SELECT
    testedRowSet.TableA_ID,
    testedRowSet.Value,
    ...
    DoesHaveRequiredValues = MAX(CASE TableB.Required     WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY testedRowSet.TableA_ID),
    HasDisqualifyingValues = MAX(CASE TableB.Disqualifies WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY testedRowSet.TableA_ID)
  FROM testedRowSet
    LEFT JOIN TableB ON testedRowSet.TableA_ID = TableB.TableA_ID
                    AND testedRowSet.Value     = TableB.Value
),

/* this row set will let us see whether a particular
   TableA_ID must have a required value */
properties AS (
  SELECT
    TableA_ID,
    MustHaveRequiredValues = MAX(CASE Required WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM TableB
  GROUP BY TableA_ID
),

/* this is where we are actually checking the previously
   obtained aggregate values of Required and Disqualifies */
tested AS (
  SELECT
    aggregated.TableA_ID,
    aggregated.Value,
    ...
  FROM aggregated
    LEFT JOIN properties ON aggregated.TableA_ID = properties.TableA_ID
  WHERE aggregated.HasDisqualifyingValues = 0
    AND (properties.TableA_ID IS NULL
      OR properties.MustHaveRequiredValues = aggregated.DoesHaveRequiredValues)
)

SELECT * FROM tested
```